# What is the correct preposition to use after "sign up"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure, phrasal-verbs

For example:

1. *The boy faked his age to sign up **in** certain websites.*
2. *The boy faked his age to sign up **to** certain websites.*
3. *The boy faked his age to sign up **for** certain websites.*
   Which one is correct?

(Also, if there's any other mistake in the sentence or if you have any suggestion, do tell.)

Answer (score 1):

The most common preposition after "sign up" is "for".

You can see the relative frequencies of prepositions (and some other words mixed in) here:

[Google Ngram viewer  sign up * *NOUN*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sign%20up%20%2A%20_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Csign%20up%20%2A%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20for%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20the%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20with%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20at%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20a%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20in%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20new%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20to%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20as%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsign%20up%20their%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0)

Your sentence 1 is very unlikely. Sentence 2 is possible, but 3 is the most likely. You might also use "at".